# Display Unique Results from Two Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: `games` and `pickems`.

Here is my schema for these models:

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "week_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "home_team_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "away_team_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "home_score",   limit: 4
  t.integer  "away_score",   limit: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  t.integer  "season_id",    limit: 4
end

create_table "pickems", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 4
  t.integer  "game_id",    limit: 4
  t.integer  "winner_id",  limit: 4
  t.integer  "score",      limit: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
end
```

**Game model**:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: 'Team'
  belongs_to :week
  belongs_to :season
end
```

**Pickem model**:

```
class Pickem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_one :game
  has_one :winner, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

In my view, I want to display all Games that do not have a Pickem associated that is referencing it.  I also want to display below all the Pickems and the game attributes associated.  What do I need to be calling from the controller and/or add to the model(s) to display this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to correct the Games/Pickem association, by adding this to the Game model:

```
has_one :pickem
```

and this to the Pickem model:

```
belongs_to :game
```

This query will retrieve all of the Games that do not have a Pickem associated:

```
@games_without_pickems = Game.joins(:pickem).group("games.id").having("COUNT('pickems.id') = 0").order("games.id")
```

change table references

This will retrieve all of the Pickems and associated Games information:

```
@pickems = Pickem.includes(:games).all
```

In your view, simply loop over both `@games_without_pickems` and `@pickems`, like this:

```
<table>
    <th>
        <td>Week</td>
        <td>Home Team</td>
        <td>Away Team</td>
        <td>Home Score</td>
        <td>Away Score</td>
        <td>Season</td>
    </th>
<% @games_without_pickems.each do |game| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= game.week.name %></td>
        <td><%= game.home_team.name %></td>
        <td><%= game.away_team.name %></td>
        <td><%= game.home_score %></td>
        <td><%= game.away_score %></td>
        <td><%= game.season.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<table>
    <th>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>Winner</td>
        <td>Score</td>

        <td>Week</td>
        <td>Home Team</td>
        <td>Away Team</td>
        <td>Home Score</td>
        <td>Away Score</td>
        <td>Season</td>
    </th>
<% @pickems.each do |pickem| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= pickem.user.name %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.winner.name %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.score %></td>

        <td><%= pickem.game.week.name %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.game.home_team.name %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.game.away_team.name %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.game.home_score %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.game.away_score %></td>
        <td><%= pickem.game.season.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

That should do it.

Comment: I am getting `Association named 'pickem' was not found on Game; perhaps you misspelled it?`. The line that contains `<% @games_without_pickems.each do |game| %>` is highlighted.

Comment: I have also tried `@games_without_pickems = Game.joins(:pickems)` with the same result.

Comment: I had missed the fact that the the `belongs_to :pickem` was missing from the Game model.  I added that at the top of my answer, and that should fix those problems.

Comment: Yes, progrès. Now I am getting `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'games.pickem_id' in 'on clause': SELECT games.* FROM games INNER JOIN pickems ON  pickems.id = games.pickem_id` It seems as though it is backwards. There is a games.id and a pickems.game_id, but the query is the other way around.

Comment: I had the relationship on the wrong model.  I updated the answer and that reflects where the id is stored.  You will need to switch the relationships on Game and Pickem, as shown at the top of the answer.

Comment: Boom. Works. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear!  And good edits on fixing the pluralization on the query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have

```
# in `pickems` table
t.integer  "game_id",    limit: 4
```

and

```
# in Pickem Model
class Pickem < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :game
  ...
end
```

I think for `has_one belongs_to`, you need to put `foreign_key` in `games` table rather than `pickems` table and it will start making sense. 
i.e.

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.integer  "pickem_id", limit: 4
  ...
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :pickem
  ...
end
```

Now

> I want to display all Games that do not have a Pickem associated that
>   is referencing it

```
Game.where(pickem_id: nil)
```

---

**One Suggestion**

Since your `Game` model belongs to multiple models like `Pickem`, `Team`, etc. so you can use [Polymorphic Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) instead.

Reason: If one of your `game` record belongs to `pickem` then other fields will be empty.